# discord.py - checking if channel id is correct

Tags: discord.py

In Discord.py I am currently coding a bot that basically acts as a system for one particular server, and isn't intended to be used as a public bot. But I still wanted to add commands in that makes it simple for administrators to configure the bot inside of Discord, all was well, until I ran into the issue of trying to check if a channel ID is actually correct or not when executing the command, but unfortunately I kept getting error after error after error.

```
@bot.command()
async def channel(ctx, type, id):
    global channel_report
    global channel_approve
    
    if id != discord.TextChannel.id:
        await ctx.send("Command terminated: bad id.")
        return
    
    if type == "report":
    #code here
    elif type == "approve":
    #code here
```

What have I been missing? I have tried to approach this many different ways, even with methods such as `get_message` , but got nowhere, and as a newish programmer, but especially new to the Discord API in particular, I'm lost. Thanks for all of those who are dedicating their time to help me, computer coding is just one of them interests.

Comment: What is it that you want to check? That the `id` provider by the user who executes the command is equal to a particular channel id?

Comment: Why `discord.TextChannel.id`? You're trying to access an instance attribute from the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming what you mean by "checking if a channel ID is correct" is that you want to make sure the given ID represents an actual channel that the bot can access. You can use [`bot.get_channel()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot%20get_channel#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_channel) to get a channel object from an ID. If the channel doesn't exist, it returns null. So you can just check if it is null.

```py
channel = bot.get_channel(000000000000000000) # try to get a channel which doesn't exist
if channel is None: # will return true as invalid channel returns null
    await ctx.send("Command terminated: bad id.")
    return
```